# Zeroing of the last byte with sscanf() on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, scanf

Here is a strange issue with Arduino function `sscanf()`. It zeroes the last byte of scanned integer value (`int`, `long`) if 1-byte value (`bool`, `byte`, `char`) follows it.

```
int someInt;
byte someByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  sscanf("10000 10", "%d %d", &someInt, &someByte);
  Serial.println(someInt); // 9984 (0x2700 not 0x2710)
  Serial.println(someByte); // 10

  sscanf("7FFF F", "%x %x", &someInt, &someByte);
  Serial.println(someInt, HEX); // 7F00 (not 7FFF)
  Serial.println(someByte, HEX); // F
}

void loop() {
  // Some code what uses someInt and someByte
}
```

If `someInt` declared in `setup()` all is OK.

I tasted it on two different Arduinos and result was the same. Why does it happen?

Comment: Have you tried `sscanf("7FFF F", "%04X %X", &someInt, &someByte);`?

Comment: And please add the code of `loop()`

Comment: Giving address of 1-byte buffer `byte` where 2-byte buffer is expected seems bad. If the language were C, *undefined behavior* would be invoked.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes (to some degree). Args of sscanf does nor expect (in formal sense) any special type, because are not type-safe. Agree, while reading documentation, pointer to integer is expected.

Comment: @MikeCAT: You don't need the "If the language was C". C++ incorporates the C _library_ by reference, so `sscanf` is also C++ with the exact same rules. And those rules indeed specify that the format string at runtime must match the static types of the following arguments, at the penalty of _Undefined Behavior_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Illegal:

```
 sscanf(buf, "%x", /* byte*/ &val )
```

sscanf family is not typesafe. the Programmer must control the code (printf family is dangerous too - sscanf is even more).

The 3rd argument (and those following, if there's more than one %d or %X) must be an adress(es) of integer(s). Integer in the sense of "natural on the platform", here 2 byte.

Your idea can be written as follows:

```
int someInt, wrkInt;
byte someByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  sscanf("10000 10", "%d %d", &someInt, &wrkInt);  // %X too, rule is the same
  someByte = wrkInt;
...
}
```